# string alignment inspired by global DNA sequence allignment

Tags: python, r, bioconductor

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
library(Biostrings)
s1 <-DNAString("ACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATCAAAGGAAACGCAAAGTTTTCACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATCAAAGGAAACGCAAAGTTTTCAAGAAGACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATCAAAGGAAACGCAAAGTTTTCAAG")
s2 <-DNAString("GTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTAAATATATGTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTGTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTAAATATATAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATCAAATATATAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATCAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATC")
pairwiseAlignment(s1,s2)
```

but with strings like this:

x123 x4531 etc.

instead of DNA alphabet characters. Is anyone aware of a package to achieve this in R or even Python. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by your strings like that? Are you looking for an aligner/string comparison approach with arbitrary alphabet rather than nucleotides/amino acids?

Comment: please provide the output of the function you want

Comment: Are mismatches always going to be equal impact or do you want a blosum like scoring matrix?

Comment: thanks @Chris_Rands. See my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Biopython's](https://github.com/biopython/biopython) `Align` module can accept an alphabet of your choice, e.g.

```
>>> from Bio import Align
>>> aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner()
>>> aligner.mode = "global"
>>> aligner.alphabet
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> aligner.alphabet += "1234567890"
>>> alignments = aligner.align("X123Y", "B12XYXYXYX")
>>> print(alignments[0])
X-123-Y-----
--||--|-----
-B12-XYXYXYX
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is that I require more than the alphabet's characters to capture 100s of strings.

Comment: @cs0815 you can modify `aligner.alphabet` to contain other characters?

Comment: Thanks. I will have a closer look at this today. My understanding is that an alphabet only has "1 character elements" - unfortunately I have 100s of unique characters (aka strings) like: abcd123 and abcd1234 thus several characters per element. Can I still use aligner.alphabet for this use case? Thanks!